# EITHER OR with Angular JS checkboxes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I'm using multiple checkboxes to filter properties using angularjs.  Currently, I am using a custom filter to show all properties of a certain type.  I have multiple checkboxes that as you check each new one it filters the results.

At present, each new checkbox you check *narrows* your search (i.e. which properties are both rural AND coastal) and I would like to *widen* the search (i.e. which properties are either rural OR coastal).  I'm really new to this.

Here is my app:

```
propertyApp.controller('PropertyListControl', function ($scope) {
$scope.properties = [
    {
        title: "Sharrow Bay Hotel",
        location:['rural', 'coastal']
    },
    {
        title: "The Royal Oak Inn",
        location:['rural']
    },
    {
        title: "Scale Hill Cottages",
        location:['urban']
    },
];

$location = {}

// Currently using this great custom filter:
}).filter('filteredLocation', function() {
    return function(properties, location) {
        var result = properties.slice(); // copy array
            angular.forEach(location, function(value, key) {
                if(value) {
                    for(var index = 0; index < result.length; index++) {
                        property = result[index];
                            if(property.location.indexOf(key) == -1) {
                            result.splice(index--,1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                return result;
            };
        });
```

And my checkboxes:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.rural"/>Rural</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.urban"/>Urban</label>
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="location.coastal"/>Coastal</label>
```

Comment: create a demo in plunker, much easier to help when we can access code and console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That filter starts with all your locations:

```
var result = properties.slice();
```

and removes any that don't match your test:

```
result.splice(index--,1);
```

Thus it's acting like an "and" since, as in your example, anything without "coastal" is removed and then anything without "Rural" is removed.  So the only items left are ones that match both conditions.

To turn it into an "or" filter I'd start with an empty array:

```
var result = [];
```

and add the results as they match (so any that match either test will be added):

```
result.push(property);
```

To avoid duplicates I've also switched the loops so the outer loop now covers the list of properties  and the inner loop goes over the list of locations to filter.  Then we can abort out of the inner loop once we find that the property matches any of the locations.

Here's the entire function:

```
.filter('filteredLocation', function() {
    return function(properties, location) {
      var result = []; 
      for(var index = 0; index < properties.length; index++) {  
         var added = false;
         angular.forEach(location, function(value, key) {         
           if(value && !added) {
              property = properties[index];
              if(property.location.indexOf(key) != -1) {
                 result.push(property);  
                 added = true; // Mark as added so we don't add duplicates
              }       
          }
       })
   };
   return result;
};
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/88fAp/1/)